# Can't remove Site Replication in Exchange 2003

Tags: exchange, exchange-2003

I am in the process of decommissioning our last Exchange 2003 server. All mailboxes and public folders have been moved, and all routing connectors as well. The Exchange 2010 server is performing exactly as it should. I want to fully remove the old exchange box from our AD, but whenever I run the uninstaller it informs that that there are still SRS links, and it cant be uninstalled until they are removed.

I don't see anything about mentioning them in the 2003 management console to be able to remove them, and ADSIedit doesn't make any mention of them either.

How can I remove this so I can uninstall exchange 2003 and turn this ancient beast off?

Exact message:

> The microsoft exchange site replication service is enabled on this server.  You cannot uninstall this server until the microsoft exchange site replication service is disabled.  Used the ESM to disable this service and try again.

Comment: Please post the exact message you receive when trying to uninstall.

Comment: edited to include error message. Also, there is no SRS tab present in the exchange manger either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recognize that error. I've gotten it twice in my life. The first time all I did was create a new SRS, then I deleted it the next day. This made the error go away.

In the other case, creating a new one did not allow me to complete the uninstall. I ended up following Microsoft's instructions on manually uninstalling Exchange 2003.

Comment: that's kinda where I was headed as well. The good news is that there isn't a whole lot that can go wrong at this point. Thanks!